# writing context-free-grammer with nltk - a rule with a terminal of two words (or more)

Tags: nlp, nltk, grammar, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

this is my assignment:

[image]

This is my implementation:

```
#TODO - construct a CFG for simple arithmetic expressions 
all_numbers = "'zero' | 'one' | 'two' | 'three' | 'four' | 'five' " \
            + "| 'six' | 'seven' | 'eight' | 'nine' | 'ten' | 'eleven' " \
            + "| 'twelve' | 'thirteen' | 'fourteen' | 'fifteen' " \
            + "| 'sixteen' | 'seventeen' | 'eighteen' | 'nineteen' | 'twenty'"
arithmetic_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring(""" 
    S -> operand operator operand | S operator operand | S operator S 
    operand -> """+all_numbers+"""
    operator -> 'plus' | 'minus' | 'times' | 'divided by'
""")
print(arithmetic_grammar)
```

Here is the result printing the CFG:
[image]

Now I'm doing this:
[image]

```
 #TODO
# "fifteen minus five"
tree2 = nltk.Tree.fromstring("(S (operand fifteen) (operator minus) (operand fifteen))")
# "four divided by two plus one"
tree3 = nltk.Tree.fromstring("(S (S (operand four) (operator divided by) (operand two)) (operator plus) (operand one))")
```

This is the result of drawing the trees:
[image]

[image]

```
def validate(tree, grammar):
    return functools.reduce(lambda accum, production: 
                               accum and production in grammar.productions(),
                            tree.productions())
```

Using it to indicate if my CFG was written correctly I get:

```
print(validate(tree2, arithmetic_grammar))
print(validate(tree3, arithmetic_grammar))
```

[image]

How can I fix this with preserving the initial 'divided by' expression to symbolize division ?
I could just change it to 'divided_by', but I want it be as is.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found to be working is:

```
#TODO - construct a CFG for simple arithmetic expressions 
all_numbers = "'zero' | 'one' | 'two' | 'three' | 'four' | 'five' " \
            + "| 'six' | 'seven' | 'eight' | 'nine' | 'ten' | 'eleven' " \
            + "| 'twelve' | 'thirteen' | 'fourteen' | 'fifteen' " \
            + "| 'sixteen' | 'seventeen' | 'eighteen' | 'nineteen' | 'twenty'"
arithmetic_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring(""" 
    S -> operand operator operand | S operator operand | S operator S 
    operand -> """+all_numbers+"""
    operator -> 'plus' | 'minus' | 'times' | 'divided' b
    b -> 'by'
""")
print(arithmetic_grammar)
```

Which gives those derivation rules:
[image]

and those derivation trees:
[image]